# Setting stringValue of a View Controllers label causes "found nil" error

Tags: macos, swift, nsviewcontroller

I'm instantiating a view controller to go into my table, and I'm receiving an error when I try to set the `stringValue` of the labels in the controllers view.

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    let postController = storyboard!.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("post") as? PostController

    // This line causes the error.
    postController!.titleLabel.stringValue = "abc"

    return postController!.view
}
```

Everything is set up correctly regarding the `IBOutlets`. I can successfully set the values from within the PostController's `viewDidLoad` method. The error only happens when I try to set them outside using the instantiated controller. I even created a test method to act as a setter but that also failed.

```
func test(a: String) {
    self.titleLabel.stringValue = a
}
```

Here is the error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: Where exactly happens that in your code? Near `postController!`?

Comment: This line where I am setting the value: `postController!.titleLabel.stringValue = postData["title"].stringValue`

Comment: Is titleLabel a UILabel? UILabel's don't have a `stringValue` property. Have you subclassed UILabel?

Comment: @Jawwad No, it's an NSTextField. This is an OS X project, not iOS.

Answer (score 2):

Having just faced this same issue, I think I figured it out. Try this:

```
//Maybe use as! to force this; if it doesn't load, you need to know about it
let postController = storyboard!.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "post") as! PostController 

//Add this    
postController.loadView() 

postController!.titleLabel.stringValue = "abc"
```

I know this post is old, but perhaps someone else will benefit from this.